# LinkedIn Login Integration in ASP.NET CORE 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linkedin-api

```
I am trying to integrate LinkedIn Login into my .Net core 2.0 project using built in authentication template. I am able to redirect control to LinkedIn login User interface, but when I enter Username and Password then I get following error.



An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while retrieving the user profile.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()

The following is Startup.cs code for LinkedIn Login Integration:

services.AddAuthentication().AddLinkedIn(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "Client_Id";
                options.ClientSecret = "Client_Secret";

            });

The following is Error Stack:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+ 
    <HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+      
    <Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: Post your code and the *full* exception, including its call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. The full exception contains any status codes, responses and inner exceptions. It may be that the URL was wrong, or the API Key is missing. Or the user didn't give permission to your web site to retrieve the profile

Comment: I'm not convinced there's much else to see. It looks like it's assuming it's received a non-empty list from the server whereas it's actually empty, hence an iteration failure. That's not likely to contain status codes or the server response. Giving us more information is a good idea, though. But I think you'll have to step through the authentication code to see exactly what the responses it's getting are (or use an HTTP proxy to intercept these) and what's going wrong.

Comment: services.AddAuthentication().AddLinkedIn(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "Client_Id";
                options.ClientSecret = "Client_Secret";


            });

Comment: When I click on LinkedIn Login Button, then LinkedIn Login Page opens. After I fill my credentials ie. Username and Password then I get the above mentioned error. The API kEY that I generated in Linkedin Developer account is correct that I am passing in my Startup.cs file.

Comment: I am using Individual Account authentication template in .Net core 2.0 for Login functionality apart from LinkedIn, Gmail and Facebook Login integration in my project.